# Can Canadian money (change) be used in the United States?

Tags: usa, canada, money, exchange

As a visitor to the US from Canada, is it possible to use Canadian money, especially coins, at businesses in the US?

What about vending machines?

Comment: There are local exceptions that accept Canadian money at par, mostly for tourist promotions, (Jay  Peak, Vt),  Myrtle Beach, SC) for the later: http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/2016/02/03/myrtle-beach-loonies-at-par_n_9152058.html

Comment: When I worked at a department store in Bellingham, WA (30ish miles from the boarder), we accepted all Canadian currency. If I remember correctly the mall in town did as well.

Comment: Even [Canadian vending machines don’t accept Canadian coins](http://www.marketwatch.com/story/new-canadian-coins-rejected-by-machines-2012-05-01). The new loonies and toonies are not backward-compatible.

Comment: The simple answer ... some US businesses will accept Canadian money, some will not .... of those that do, some will accept coins, some will only take bills (and give change in US coins ;-) ... some older vending machines will accept Canadian quarters, most newer ones won't.  So don't count on using Canadian money 100%.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/can-i-use-usd-in-canada?rq=1

Comment: Yes and no. In general, a vendor may accept anything as payment. But a purchaser cannot demand that anything but ['legal tender'](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/faqs/Currency/Pages/legal-tender.aspx) be accepted by a vendor who serves the general public.

Comment: These answers appear to be talking about the US near Canada? Because in the middle and below of the US, the answer is NO. Not venders, not vending machines. Just NO.

Comment: @MarkMayo Yeah, it's related, but it's a very poor relative. Canadian businesses have almost always had no problem taking US dollars, but they very rarely give anything close to a fair exchange rate.

Comment: I could never understand the use of vending machines.  Usually nasty overpriced crud in there...you'd think for the quality and price it would take anything from USD to CAD to Chuckie Cheese Tokens.

Comment: @user2338816 As your own link states, a purchaser can't even demand that legal tender be accepted by a merchant. 'Legal tender' status just means that _people who are owed debts_ must accept it, not that anyone selling anything must do so. It's perfectly legal, for example, for a merchant to only accept card payments or only accept checks.

Comment: @trevor Having lived in Bellingham mostly, since 1988, I experienced the same thing.  However, your comment sounds past-tense, and more recently, most places including Bellis Fair mall have stopped accepting Canadian change at par, and may even have stopped taking Canadian cash.  (Probably because VISA became more popular, so there's been less interest in people trying to spend Canadian cash, so less of a need for stores to care enough to accept it.)  Though as Necreaux's answer suggests, we generally don't care to differentiate the pennies (presuming less than 5 of them in a purchase).

Comment: @Auspex : Right.  Those of us living near the border recognized some border behaviors are a bit unusual, so there was inclination to share details of these areas, which are an exception we know about, so people may better know the full story.  Bellingham is 30 miles/minutes (by car) from Canada.  Mt. Vernon, which is 60 miles/minutes from Canada, never (that I've noticed) accepted Canadian money as widely as Bellingham (or other spots even closer to the Canadian border).  (Nor Seattle or anywhere else further from the border.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Technically no, practically speaking yes.

Many of the coins look the same as US coins at a first glance, so careless clerks may accept them. I am in the US and often find myself with Canadian pennies and quarters which are very similar to the US counterparts. Having all the new coins in the US in recent years makes it even harder for people to tell the difference. Generally, vending machines will not accept them.

It's probably technically illegal to pass them off as US currency though, it might be classifiable as counterfeiting or fraud, but it happens all the time, intentional or not.

EDIT: To summarize discussion in comments...

There may be stores near the border that officially accept CAD. That would be completely legitimate. I live in a border state but have never seen any. In all fairness I live 200 miles from the border but I do go near the border several times a year. I also have never specifically looked. It is probably limited to tourist locations.

In reference to careless clerks, using CAD for an entire transaction is unlikely to work. 4 CAD quarters would be way less likely to work than 3 USD and 1 CAD.

I'm still skeptical on the vending machine front. I've tried it without success and stopped trying, but maybe there are vending machines that would accept them. A whole discussion on how they work would probably be off-topic, but I think it has something to do with whether they detect a coin based on size or electrical resistance.

Comment: The USA might be the only country you can spend those Canadian pennies now.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47297/discussion-on-answer-by-necreaux-can-canadian-money-change-be-used-in-the-unit).

Answer (score 31):

Generally not. Your Canadian money will definitely not work in US vending machines.  Some border towns accept Canadian currency, but the further from the border you get, the less likely it is.

Comment: As an American living in Canada, I can assure you many places around the states accidentally take Canadian *coins*.

Comment: @corsiKa Careless store clerks, sure. But vending machines? Don't those normally have measures to only accept the types of coins they're expecting?

Comment: It would appear people on this site use vending machines approximately 10000x more than I do...

Comment: Distinguishing US currency from Canadian is remarkably simple for a machine - All you need is a magnet.  Canadian nickels, dimes, and quarters all contain ferrous metal, and can be picked up with a magnet, while their US counterparts do not.  (Pennies are non-ferrous in both countries, unless you count the US 1943 steel penny, but A.) most machines don't take pennies at all and B.) anyone who owns any of those is unlikely to spend them.)

Comment: Exactly this - the amount of offense you will cause a store clerk when trying to pass a Canadian coin is almost entirely related to your distance from the border. Americans from New England (far NE US) have expressed incredulity to me that anyone would even bother to notice; some Texans see it as a federal crime akin to money laundering.

Comment: @DewiMorgan - Which makes me wonder - how do people in southern Texas feel about people paying with *Mexican* currency?  If this theory holds near all international borders, you'd think pesos would be seen near that border, but I suspect this occurs far less frequently.  (Though there is a much more significant difference in value in that exchange.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Pesos aren't accepted anywhere, far as I know - maybe right *at* the border? But I suspect this is because they don't use dollars and cents and same-sized currency.
I noticed a similar but inverse thing with Scotland: Scotland prints its own notes of British pounds Sterling with a different design. This Scottish currency is legal tender throughout the UK, but the further south from the border you get, the less likely someone is to know that, and to accept it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I'm about 90% sure that every vending machine ever considers only size and weight. Gumball machines only consider size, even (and could be fooled with an appropriately-sized piece of plastic or whatever).

Comment: @KRyan I've had enough experience operating vending machines (pop, snacks, pinball and video games) to know that most of them that are more complicated than a gumball machine use magnets to prevent slugs (and Canadian coins) from being accepted.  A coin acceptor is also designed to reject plastic, etc. because of the lower density.

Comment: @MontyHarder Hm, I was always told that weights were used, not magnets. Certainly not anything like an expert, though.

Comment: @Dewi: actually Scottish banknotes *aren't* legal tender (http://www.scotbanks.org.uk/legal_position.php), but what you say is true about acceptance varying by latitude.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I suppose it could more correctly be called "legally recognized currency", but feh. I tend to disagree with linguistic prescriptionism (alibi, beg the question, trauma, singular they, decimate, may...) and would instead argue that as well as the largely useless meaning used in legal jargon ("money you can't legally refuse as debt repayment, eg 20 or fewer pennies"), it has the far more useful and commonly-understood lay meaning of "money that is legal to tender, and which you won't get arrested for passing".

Comment: @KRyan Vending machines may check the magnetic properties of the metal used in the coin. I think it was when the Sacajawea dollars were first introduced, I read about how much effort went into finding a metal that was gold-colored, but had roughly the same magnetic "signature" as existing silver-colored coins.

Comment: @DewiMorgan: true, but there are some shops down here in the south where you'll have a slightly easier time spending Euros than Scottish pounds, and people don't call Euros legal tender. Fair enough in your case, you know what you meant, but I think commonly people use the term because they're genuinely unaware of the law, not because they're aware of it but use the term informally to mean something different. Doesn't really matter either way until someone's getting shirty with the driver in the bus queue that their 20 is legal tender, as if that's somehow important :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop That's a different case. Scottish notes are considered absolutely proper for payment in Scotland, and ime in the border counties in England. & should be accepted in banks through the rest of England _at par_. Euros _may_ be accepted but it's purely the choice of the proprietor, and banks _won't_ accept them at par. They'll apply their usurious exchange rates (I was queuing at a Llloyd's bank last week, looking at the sign that said "we don't charge a foreign exchange fee"—while also noting that the spread between their Euro buy & sell rates was 15%!  I should  _hope_ not!)

Comment: @SteveJessop Good point, though. I wonder if there've been any cases where someone has got in serious legal trouble for having the money in euros and trying to pay with them ("But the UK is part of Europe! I didn't realize!"). Or Scottish notes, come to that.

Answer (score 8):

Canadian money in the US is generally not accepted, and will definitely not be taken at the abysmal current rates, unlike US money which you can sometimes use in Canada.

However, in my experience quarters are nearly always interchangeable, I've used US quarters in machines in Canada and American businesses have accepted Canadian quarters in the past.

Comment: US Quarters have almost always been accepted in Canada, in vending machines.  The reverse has _never_ been true--except perhaps on the odd occasion when Canadian currency has been more valuable. The coins have different weights, and the machines are more than capable of differentiating.

Comment: @Auspex hm quite possible, maybe I need to refresh my memory with a trip to the US soon

Comment: Rejection by vending machines are generally how I become aware that some clerk has slipped me a less valuable Canadian coin.

Comment: Replace "can sometimes use in Canada" with "can always use in Canada"

Comment: @Insane hm that's not quite true

Comment: @blackbird57 I don't think a retailer has ever turned me down, but then again that just might be Ontario for you. Half of them actually will use the exchange rate, the other half take $1 US as $1 CDN.

Comment: When the US dollar was lowest, US coins were not accepted, eg. T&T supermarket. You never get more than par in Canada for US coins IME, not that it makes much difference- it would take a pocket full of US coins to add up to much- no $1 or $2 coins in common circulation.

Answer (score 8):

Devices that take coins in the US are specifically designed to reject all foreign coins, and most will do so quite reliably. If you happen to find one that does not, it would be the equivalent of using a slug rather than a coin in terms of what the potential penalty might be.

In general, foreign coins are **much** less acceptable than bank notes in most countries (for example, usually banks don't want them and won't supply them), and the US is certainly no exception. There may be a few places in border towns that depend on Canadian tourism that will accept coins and/or bank notes, but it would be stated explicitly. It might even be possible to get a preferential exchange rate, as a promotional deal, but that would be by far the exception.

Comment: Resident of the Buffalo/Niagara region here.  Acceptance of of Canadian currency is not uncommon but the exchange rate is **definitely not** preferential.  Canadians come here to avoid the PST & GST.  Erie County's paltry 8% sales tax is a remarkable savings for Canadians in its own right.  Most folks just use plastic when across the border.

Comment: @tjd There are a number of Western NY tourist-oriented businesses that currently accept Canadian dollars cash **at par**, and others that offer a discount. Naturally this is not made obvious to residents as it would probably just p*ss them off. Unfortunately (unlike HST) there is no way for non-residents to get a rebate on NY state sales tax, so often Canadians end up paying both. [random example](http://jaypeakresort.com/about/jay-peaks-exchange-rate-policy/)

Comment: "It might even be possible to get a preferential exchange rate" Perhaps. But, in general, when you're in one country and trying to use the currency of another country in a shop, the exchange rate you get is truly abyssmal.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

When I was very young (some 55 years ago), living in Lake Hills WA, a small bedroom community just outside Bellevue WA, which in turn is just outside of Seattle WA, Canadian coins and American coins routinely traded one-for-one.  I would be very surprised to learn that this was no longer the case, as Seattle is quite close to the Canadian border.

I saw the same thing in St Petersburg FL in 1982.  During the high season, the town was close to 40% Canadian tourists.

While there was, in St Pete at that time, about a 20% difference in the value of the coins, according to the exchange rate, the local merchants didn't worry about it.  They figured they'd make it back when they passed the coin along to someone else, and it made it easier on the Canadian tourists who were paying the bills.

Comment: Proximity has little to do with value, take a look at current exchange rates and you'll see why no one wants Canadian money. US money is generally worth more but the difference has always been negligible down to quarters and dimes

Comment: "I would be very surprised to learn that this was no longer the case, as Seattle is quite close to the Canadian border." Well be surprised then. About the early 80s, someone, Federal Reserve, changed the rules and banks stopped taking Canadian coinage as American they had before. Merchants followed suit, and the amount of incidental Canadian Coinage in circulation is much less now.

Comment: yep, I've lived in Seattle on and off since 2005 and have never once seen anyone use Canadian currency here.

Answer (score 3):

Anything larger than 25 cents, definitely not.

For pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters, sometimes.

In Michigan (where I grew up, which is near Canada), almost always. In New York, where I live now, clerks have rejected them.

I've never tried to use more than one or two at once, anywhere.

Vending machines will reject them.

Answer (score 2):

I will add to the existing answers that most Canadian coins, over the last several years (or decades, for some denominations), had been made of (some variety of) a magnetic steel alloy. US vending machines most definitely will not accept any coins made out of a magnetic alloy, and the Canadian government (unlike the US one, ironically) is trying to pull the existing old (including non-magnetic) coins out of circulation (for metal reclamation - many of them are worth more as scrap metal than face value).

So anything you got in recent Canadian change is probably not going to be accepted in a US vending machine, but if you somehow have Canadian coins from the 1980s or earlier (can't recall where exactly the cut-off date is - and it's different for different denominations - but 1980s should be safe enough), they might be accepted, as the size is identical, and the composition is similar.
Of course, if you have Canadian coins denominated 10 cents and up from 1967 or earlier, they are silver, and worth an awful lot more than face value. And, also of course, knowingly passing Canadian currency (either coins or banknotes, though of course the latter is much less likely) as US currency of the same numeric face value (and thus much higher exchange rate) is very illegal fraud either way.

Answer (score 2):

In the eyes of the US Treasury I am sure the answer is absolutely not.  Store clerks will sometimes uncaringly or unknowly accept Canadian coins.  Any merchant can decide for themselves to take Canadian money in an effort to boost sales just as they could decide to accept Chuck E Cheese tokens if they thought it could boost sales.

Comment: The U.S. Treasury doesn't care what coins a shop accepts. As you say, a shop can _choose_ to accept anything it wants in payment for goods. All the U.S. Treasury cares about is that you can't refuse to accept U.S. currency in payment of a debt. (Note that this is, technically, irrelevant to shops because you're not in debt to the shop: you're making an offer to exchange money for goods. But you are in debt to a restaurant when you eat your meal before paying for it.)

Comment: Usually that money will be deposited in a bank where the federal government does start to have a say

Comment: @teambob: as far as that is concerned, the government will take an extreme interest if the store tries to deposit Chuck E Cheese tokens claiming they're US dollars, but not at the point you accept tokens in your store instead of dollars. Either federal or local authorities might become interested in how you're reporting these token or Canadian-dollar transactions for sales/corporate/income tax.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_currency#United_States is quite fun, to see how these things sometimes kind of work (Ithaca hours) and sometimes very much don't (United States Private Dollars).

Answer (score 2):

There are businesses along the Canadian/US border that are aware of Canadian currency and may accept it at the appropriate exchange rate.

In particular, one company that I worked for on their point of sales software had a not insignificant portion of the business in towns like International Falls and Port Huron be from Canadians.  The cashier would select the option for the tender being in Canadian currency and the current exchange rate would be applied to the currency.  Outside of those two stores, it is still possible (though neither *required* nor are the cashiers necessarily trained on that feature of the software).

And so yes. There are places were using Canadian currency (both bills and coins) is perfectly acceptable within the United States.  Chances are other companies that have businesses that border the border will have similar policies.

Comment: This answer is definitely interesting, in that it would appear that some businesses might do more than the _look the other way_ acceptance of coinage.

Answer (score 1):

YES. But you should not rely upon it. There is no regulation preventing the acceptance of Canadian currency. If the vendor chooses to accept it, it is accepted. You may struggle to find a store that implements a policy of acceptance but it has happened.

Ask.

Hotels will generally place a notice above the reception desk, and you may be gouged for their inconvenience on the exchange rate.